# JQuery Smooth Lightbox zoomin

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery lightbox with smooth zooming animation 
it should zoom form the center of window. I searched many time I am beginner please help me for this

Answer (score 0):

Try http://fancybox.net/. It has many zooming effects and more options.